# Parse a user input string into Day type and subtract two dates in Haskell

Tags: date, parsing, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I need some help. I will like to create a function that takes in a user's input in the format yyyy, mm, dd and convert it to type Day in order to use diffDays.

This is what I tried:

```
today :: IO (Integer, Int, Int)
today = getCurrentTime >>= return . toGregorian . utctDay

getDiffDays' :: IO Integer
getDiffDays' = do
     putStr "What is your birthdate (year, month, day)?: "
     dateOfBirth <- getLine
     let dob = read dateOfBirth :: Day
     return diffDays today dob
```

Comment: Start by breaking the problem into smaller pieces. Do you know how to get input from the user in Haskell? Do you know how to declare a custom type? Or is there an existing type that you can use? Do you know basic Haskell syntax? If not, then you should find a book or tutorial.

Comment: please share some code

Comment: I edited with the attempt I tried. Thanks for looking.

Comment: You should keep the code in your question and post an answer explaining how you solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want something below,

```
import Data.Time.Calender
import Data.List (intercalate)

replace :: String -> String
replace src = intercalate "-" $ words $ filter (/= ',') src

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- Example input: 2018, 11, 12
  dayString <- getLine
  let day = read (replace dayString) :: Day
  -- Example output: 2018-11-12
  print day
```

the problem was that `Day` expect to read of format `YYYY-MM-DD` but `YYYY, MM, DD`